# Node async map utility is not working as per expectation for huge amount of data

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

What i am trying to do is fetch fitbit user's from database then process one by one and call three api endpoints for each user. Everything works fine but when number of users increased drastically then i am unable to persist refresh token for some user.

```
   var fitbit_instances = []; // this array will have instances for each user
    User.find(where, {}, function (err, fitbit_users) {
        async.map(fitbit_users, function (v, cbk) {
            // make instance of api for each user
            fitbit_instances.push(new Fitbit(config.fitbit));
            var index = fitbit_instances.length - 1;
            // then save data for each endpoint
            async.series([
                    function (callback) {
                        // api end point 1
                        fitbit_instances[index].request({
                            uri: "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/" + $newdate + ".json",
                            method: 'GET'
                        }, function (err, data, res) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err, null);
                            } else {
                                callback(null, udata);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    function (callback) {
                        // api end point 2
                        fitbit_instances[index].request({
                            uri: "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/" + $newdate + ".json",
                            method: 'GET'
                        }, function (err, data, res) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err, null);
                            } else {
                                callback(null, udata);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    function (callback) {
                        // api end point 3
                        fitbit_instances[index].request({
                            uri: "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/" + $newdate + ".json",
                            method: 'GET'
                        }, function (err, data, res) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err, null);
                            } else {
                                callback(null, udata);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                ],
                function (err, data) {
                    cbk(null);
                });
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({message: 'Database error occurs.', error: err});
            }
            else {
                res.status(200).json({message: 'Success', data: [], error: {}});
            }
        });
    });
```